Как отключить вывод результата выполнения команды в cmd
Мне надо отключить вывод результата выполнения команды в cmd, @echo off не помогает
Вот команда которую я выполняю:
mkdir C:\Space & cd C:\Space && C: && bitsadmin /transfer spacealphadownload /download /priority foreground https://asdashda.5v.pl/Space.zip C:\Space\Space.zip && tar -xf Space.zip && jdk\bin\java.exe -Djava.library.path=natives -jar SpaceAlphaStarter.jar


Например перенаправить вывод в файл вашакоманда > log.txt

ну или >nul (вывод в никуда)
